# Still having citation problems

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, citing, bibliographystyle

[image: image of 1st chapter]Following is `main.tex` of MWE

```
 \documentclass{report}
 \usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{blue}{RGB}{243,102,25}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\input{structure}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{Chapter1}
\input{ch1} 
\chapter*{Bibliography}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\textcolor{blue}{Bibliography}} \printbibliography[heading=none]
\end{document}
```

Following is structure.tex of MWE:

```
\usepackage[
```

backend=biber,
style=numeric,
sorting=nyt,
sortcites=true,
autopunct=true,
autolang=hyphen,
abbreviate=false,
backref=true,
]{biblatex}
\defbibheading{bibempty}{}
\addbibresource{Reference.bib}

Following is Reference.bib for MWE:

```
@book{1.1, title={Securing critical information infrastructure: Global perspectives and practices}, author={Sharma, Munish}, year={2017}, publisher={Institute for Defence Studies and Analyses} }
```

Following is Ch1.tex of MWE:

```
The reference used here is \cite{1.1}
```

This works well and gives output pdf file.

Comment: Please make a full but minimal example others can copy and test as is. See https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228, we cannot test your code here as there is no document class (which might contain stuf that are important)

Comment: Normally `\chapter*{Bibliography}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\textcolor{blue}{Bibliography}}` are bit needed. And where does `\chapterimage` come from?

Comment: @daleif there is an image file to be placed at the top of the first page of each chapter. So, \chapterimage is used.

Comment: None of the code you provided defines \chapterimage and thus your code cannot be test by us. So how exactly are we suppose to help you?

Comment: A simple question: Did you remember to run `biber` on your project and then compiling twice? Depending on your editor this does not happen automatically.

Comment: The only class in my latex dist that provides `\chapterimage` is `litesolution.cls`

Comment: There's no way to know if this is the problem without an MWE, but you seem to call \addbibresource twice with the same argument. One of those uses appears to be in the body, where \addbibresource cannot be used.

Comment: As ValerieJeffcott says: `\addbibresource{References.bib}` is definitely wrong in the document body (and `\printbibliography` can only sensibly used in the document body), so it appears that the first code snippet should lose the `\addbibresource{References.bib}`. The LaTeX run on your document should finish without errors. You should then run Biber (see https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/63852/35864 and https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/154751/35864) and then LaTeX twice more.

Comment: @ValerieJeffcott MWE main.tex: \documentclass{report}
\usepackage{xcolor} 
\definecolor{blue}{RGB}{243,102,25}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{enumitem} 
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{booktabs} 
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\input{structure}
\begin{document}
\chapter{Chapter1}
  \input{ch1}
\chapter*{Bibliography}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\textcolor{blue}{Bibliography}}
\printbibliography
\end{document}

Comment: @ValerieJeffcott ch1.tex MWE   The reference used here is \cite{1.1}.   and for the MWE reference.bib is @book{1.1,
  title={Securing critical information infrastructure: Global perspectives and practices},
  author={Sharma, Munish},
  year={2017},
  publisher={Institute for Defence Studies and Analyses}
}         The document appears in Overleaf, BUT  Chapter1 is written as heading twice in the same page and Bibliography heading appears in an empty page and in the next page with the bib entry

Comment: @ValerieJeffcott   structure.tex for MWE: \usepackage[style=numeric,citestyle=numeric,sorting=nyt,sortcites=true,autopunct=true,autolang=hyphen,hyperref=true,abbreviate=false,backref=true,,backend=biber]{biblatex} \defbibheading{bibempty}{} \addbibresource{Reference.bib}

Comment: @daleif I have commented out \chapterimage. If I wanted to use \chapterimage how should I define it and where? The cls file used in overleaf for Legrand orangebook is ltxmdf.cls. Do i need to add another cls file? Or do i simply add the definition of \chapterimage in structure file?

Comment: @ValerieJeffcott in the legrand book which i am using there are errors with tikz, like \usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,calc,positioning} gives Missing \begin{document}. \tikzset{block/.style={draw,thick,text width=2cm,minimum height=1cm,ali.... gives Undefined control sequence. I have included the tikz package but still this happens.

Comment: Please edit the code into your question: It's really hard to read in the comments.

Comment: @moewe code is edited. MWE gives pdf file where Chapter1 is written as heading twice in the same page and Bibliography heading appears in an empty page and in the next page with the bib entry.  How can i fix the tikz error of the actual file that i am working on?

Comment: I've shown in my answer below how you can avoid the duplicate heading. The example does not reproduce a TikZ error. I suggest you ask a new question with suitable MWE about that.

Comment: @moewe Thank You. I made the change you suggested and the double bibliography headings are gone. However, double chapter heading still there. What to do?

Comment: This is just the chapter heading style: It shows "Chapter n <chapter title>". If you want to change that, ask a new question. It has nothing to do with the bibliography.

Comment: @moewe Thank You. I just posted a tikz related MWE. I also need to thank  
Valerie Jeffcott and  daleif . Thank You ... to all of you for helping me out with latex related errors

Answer (score 2):

In the example you get double the bibliography headings and empty pages, because the example explicitly produces a new "Bibliography" chapter with `\chapter*` and then `\printbibliography` does the same.

Ideally you would just let `\printbibliography` generate the heading. If you want the bibliography to appear in the table of contents, use the option `heading=bibintoc`. This will not, however, make the entry in the ToC blue. If you need that, it is probably easiest to manually take over printing the heading and tell `biblatex` not to print any heading with `heading=none,`.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{blue}{RGB}{243,102,25}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[
  backend=biber,
  style=numeric,
  sorting=nyt,
  sortcites=true,
  autopunct=true,
  autolang=hyphen,
  abbreviate=false,
  backref=true,
]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{Chapter1}
The reference used here is \cite{sigfridsson}
\chapter*{Bibliography}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\textcolor{blue}{Bibliography}}
\printbibliography[heading=none]
\end{document}
```

[image: ToC]